# What is Android's icicle parameter?

Tags: android

I've noticed in some coding people use icicle with the onCreate method, and I was wondering what it is exactly:

```
public class About extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.whatup);
    }
```

Is this the same thing as `savedInstanceState`?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

"icicle" is sometimes used as the name of the parameter because `onSaveInstanceState()` used to be called `onFreeze()`.

Comment: Ah..I get it now.  I got that analogy. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

The name isn't magic.  It's just a placeholder for one of the formal parameters.  As shown by [the API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)), onCreate takes one Bundle parameter.  It's up to you what to call it.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that to me. Excuse my ignorance, but what is it that I'm manipulating once I pass it through to the class?  I'm trying to wrap my head around this.  
I guess with savedInstanceState it's suppose to pull in the last saved data when the user restores the activity again.

Thank you for helping understand this. I appreciate it big time!

Comment: What do you mean "once I pass it through"?  When Android calls onSaveInstanceState, that gives you the chance to save your state in a Bundle (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html).  Later, when your app is restarted, you will be passed a Bundle to restore data from.