# What is a frozen icicle?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is android's icicle parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919153/what-is-androids-icicle-parameter)

I've seen the term "frozen icicle" used in several places in the Android API documentation, but nowhere have I ever seen it *explained*. What is a frozen icicle? I had at first thought that it meant the triangles used when selecting text, but now I wonder if it has something to do with saved instance state.

Answer (score 2):

The first answer here seems most likely:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/923963/4819445

Comment: It's okay to answer duplicate questions, but if you're just going to link to another answer it should probably just be a comment.